# Function runs into an error after successfully processing the first few results

Tags: r

I have some data that I am trying to apply a function over. It goes to a URL, collects the JSON data and then stores it into a folder on my computer.

I apply the following code:

```
downloadAndStoreJSONData <- function(jsonLink, provinceFolderLoc, provincia, rowID, groupID, provincesFolderLocationsNames){
  print(paste("Processing: ", provincia, ".", "Group number: ", groupID, "Row number: ", rowID))
  jsonLink = jsonLink %>% unlist()
  JSON_in = fromJSON(jsonLink)
  write_json(JSON_in, paste(provinceFolderLoc, "/", provincesFolderLocationsNames, ".json", sep = ""))
  Sys.sleep(10)
}

pmap(list(df2$json_link, df2$titleFolderLocations, df2$provincia, df2$rowID, df2$groupID, df2$provincesFolderLocationsNames), ~downloadAndStoreJSONData(..1, ..2, ..3, ..4, ..5, ..6))
```

Which works, my output is the following (with the error)

```
[1] "Processing:  Albacete . Group number:  1 Row number:  1"
[1] "Processing:  Albacete . Group number:  2 Row number:  2"
[1] "Processing:  Albacete . Group number:  3 Row number:  3"
[1] "Processing:  Albacete . Group number:  4 Row number:  4"
[1] "Processing:  Albacete . Group number:  5 Row number:  5"
[1] "Processing:  Albacete . Group number:  6 Row number:  6"
[1] "Processing:  Albacete . Group number:  9 Row number:  9"
[1] "Processing:  Albacete . Group number:  10 Row number:  10"
[1] "Processing:  Alicante/Alacant . Group number:  1 Row number:  11"
[1] "Processing:  Alicante/Alacant . Group number:  2 Row number:  12"
[1] "Processing:  Alicante/Alacant . Group number:  3 Row number:  13"
[1] "Processing:  Alicante/Alacant . Group number:  4 Row number:  14"
 Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : 
  OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 104
```

Traceback:

```
 Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : 
  OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 104 
9.
open.connection(con, "rb") 
8.
open(con, "rb") 
7.
parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) 
6.
parseJSON(txt, bigint_as_char) 
5.
parse_and_simplify(txt = txt, simplifyVector = simplifyVector, 
    simplifyDataFrame = simplifyDataFrame, simplifyMatrix = simplifyMatrix, 
    flatten = flatten, ...) 
4.
fromJSON(jsonLink) 
3.
downloadAndStoreJSONData(..1, ..2, ..3, ..4, ..5, ..6) 
2.
.f(.l[[1L]][[i]], .l[[2L]][[i]], .l[[3L]][[i]], .l[[4L]][[i]], 
    .l[[5L]][[i]], .l[[6L]][[i]], ...) 
1.
pmap(list(df2$json_link, df2$titleFolderLocations, df2$provincia, 
    df2$rowID, df2$groupID, df2$provincesFolderLocationsNames), 
    ~downloadAndStoreJSONData(..1, ..2, ..3, ..4, ..5, ..6))
```

Why is it processing the data up to a point and then just stopping? Is the website kicking me off their servers?

When I ran the function with a `Sys.sleep` of 1 I got this error sooner:

```
[1] "Processing:  Albacete . Group number:  1 Row number:  1"
[1] "Processing:  Albacete . Group number:  2 Row number:  2"
[1] "Processing:  Albacete . Group number:  3 Row number:  3"
[1] "Processing:  Albacete . Group number:  4 Row number:  4"
[1] "Processing:  Albacete . Group number:  5 Row number:  5"
 Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : 
  OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 104
```

Should I increase the sleeping time, and some random noise into it?

**NOTE:** Applying the function will take 5-10 minutes to process.

Data:

```
df2 <- structure(list(index = c("2.1.1", "2.1.2", "2.1.3", "2.1.4", 
"2.1.5", "2.1.6", "2.1.9", "2.1.10", "2.2.1", "2.2.2", "2.2.3", 
"2.2.4", "2.2.5", "2.2.6", "2.2.9", "2.2.10", "2.3.1", "2.3.2", 
"2.3.3", "2.3.4"), title = c("Indicadores de renta media y mediana", 
"Distribución por fuente de ingresos", "Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo de determinados umbrales fijos por sexo", 
"Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo de determinados umbrales fijos por sexo y tramos de edad", 
"Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo de determinados umbrales fijos por sexo y nacionalidad", 
"Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo/encima de determinados umbrales relativos por sexo", 
"Índice de Gini y Distribución de la renta P80/P20", "Indicadores demográficos", 
"Indicadores de renta media y mediana", "Distribución por fuente de ingresos", 
"Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo de determinados umbrales fijos por sexo", 
"Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo de determinados umbrales fijos por sexo y tramos de edad", 
"Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo de determinados umbrales fijos por sexo y nacionalidad", 
"Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo/encima de determinados umbrales relativos por sexo", 
"Índice de Gini y Distribución de la renta P80/P20", "Indicadores demográficos", 
"Indicadores de renta media y mediana", "Distribución por fuente de ingresos", 
"Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo de determinados umbrales fijos por sexo", 
"Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo de determinados umbrales fijos por sexo y tramos de edad"
), link = c("https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30656&L=0", 
"https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30813&L=0", "https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30657&L=0", 
"https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30659&L=0", "https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30660&L=0", 
"https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30661&L=0", "https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=37678&L=0", 
"https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30814&L=0", "https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30833&L=0", 
"https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30834&L=0", "https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30835&L=0", 
"https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30836&L=0", "https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30837&L=0", 
"https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30838&L=0", "https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=37733&L=0", 
"https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30841&L=0", "https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30842&L=0", 
"https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30843&L=0", "https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30844&L=0", 
"https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30845&L=0"), provincia = c("Albacete", 
"Albacete", "Albacete", "Albacete", "Albacete", "Albacete", "Albacete", 
"Albacete", "Alicante/Alacant", "Alicante/Alacant", "Alicante/Alacant", 
"Alicante/Alacant", "Alicante/Alacant", "Alicante/Alacant", "Alicante/Alacant", 
"Alicante/Alacant", "Almería", "Almería", "Almería", "Almería"
), provincesFolderLocationsNames = c("Albacete", "Albacete", 
"Albacete", "Albacete", "Albacete", "Albacete", "Albacete", "Albacete", 
"Alicante_Alacant", "Alicante_Alacant", "Alicante_Alacant", "Alicante_Alacant", 
"Alicante_Alacant", "Alicante_Alacant", "Alicante_Alacant", "Alicante_Alacant", 
"Almería", "Almería", "Almería", "Almería"), provincesFolderLocations = c("/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Albacete", 
"/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Albacete", "/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Albacete", 
"/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Albacete", "/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Albacete", 
"/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Albacete", "/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Albacete", 
"/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Albacete", "/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Alicante_Alacant", 
"/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Alicante_Alacant", 
"/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Alicante_Alacant", 
"/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Alicante_Alacant", 
"/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Alicante_Alacant", 
"/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Alicante_Alacant", 
"/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Alicante_Alacant", 
"/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Alicante_Alacant", 
"/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Almería", "/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Almería", 
"/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Almería", "/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Almería"
), titleFolderLocationsNames = c("Indicadores de renta media y mediana", 
"Distribución por fuente de ingresos", "Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo de determinados umbrales fijos por sexo", 
"Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo de determinados umbrales fijos por sexo y tramos de edad", 
"Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo de determinados umbrales fijos por sexo y nacionalidad", 
"Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo_encima de determinados umbrales relativos por sexo", 
"Índice de Gini y Distribución de la renta P80_P20", "Indicadores demográficos", 
"Indicadores de renta media y mediana", "Distribución por fuente de ingresos", 
"Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo de determinados umbrales fijos por sexo", 
"Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo de determinados umbrales fijos por sexo y tramos de edad", 
"Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo de determinados umbrales fijos por sexo y nacionalidad", 
"Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo_encima de determinados umbrales relativos por sexo", 
"Índice de Gini y Distribución de la renta P80_P20", "Indicadores demográficos", 
"Indicadores de renta media y mediana", "Distribución por fuente de ingresos", 
"Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo de determinados umbrales fijos por sexo", 
"Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo de determinados umbrales fijos por sexo y tramos de edad"
), titleFolderLocations = c("/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Albacete/Indicadores de renta media y mediana", 
"/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Albacete/Distribución por fuente de ingresos", 
"/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Albacete/Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo de determinados umbrales fijos por sexo", 
"/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Albacete/Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo de determinados umbrales fijos por sexo y tramos de edad", 
"/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Albacete/Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo de determinados umbrales fijos por sexo y nacionalidad", 
"/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Albacete/Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo_encima de determinados umbrales relativos por sexo", 
"/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Albacete/Índice de Gini y Distribución de la renta P80_P20", 
"/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Albacete/Indicadores demográficos", 
"/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Alicante_Alacant/Indicadores de renta media y mediana", 
"/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Alicante_Alacant/Distribución por fuente de ingresos", 
"/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Alicante_Alacant/Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo de determinados umbrales fijos por sexo", 
"/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Alicante_Alacant/Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo de determinados umbrales fijos por sexo y tramos de edad", 
"/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Alicante_Alacant/Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo de determinados umbrales fijos por sexo y nacionalidad", 
"/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Alicante_Alacant/Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo_encima de determinados umbrales relativos por sexo", 
"/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Alicante_Alacant/Índice de Gini y Distribución de la renta P80_P20", 
"/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Alicante_Alacant/Indicadores demográficos", 
"/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Almería/Indicadores de renta media y mediana", 
"/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Almería/Distribución por fuente de ingresos", 
"/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Almería/Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo de determinados umbrales fijos por sexo", 
"/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Almería/Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo de determinados umbrales fijos por sexo y tramos de edad"
), json_link = list("https://servicios.ine.es/wstempus/js/es/DATOS_TABLA/30656?tip=AM&", 
    "https://servicios.ine.es/wstempus/js/es/DATOS_TABLA/30813?tip=AM&", 
    "https://servicios.ine.es/wstempus/js/es/DATOS_TABLA/30657?tip=AM&", 
    "https://servicios.ine.es/wstempus/js/es/DATOS_TABLA/30659?tip=AM&", 
    "https://servicios.ine.es/wstempus/js/es/DATOS_TABLA/30660?tip=AM&", 
    "https://servicios.ine.es/wstempus/js/es/DATOS_TABLA/30661?tip=AM&", 
    "https://servicios.ine.es/wstempus/js/es/DATOS_TABLA/37678?tip=AM&", 
    "https://servicios.ine.es/wstempus/js/es/DATOS_TABLA/30814?tip=AM&", 
    "https://servicios.ine.es/wstempus/js/es/DATOS_TABLA/30833?tip=AM&", 
    "https://servicios.ine.es/wstempus/js/es/DATOS_TABLA/30834?tip=AM&", 
    "https://servicios.ine.es/wstempus/js/es/DATOS_TABLA/30835?tip=AM&", 
    "https://servicios.ine.es/wstempus/js/es/DATOS_TABLA/30836?tip=AM&", 
    "https://servicios.ine.es/wstempus/js/es/DATOS_TABLA/30837?tip=AM&", 
    "https://servicios.ine.es/wstempus/js/es/DATOS_TABLA/30838?tip=AM&", 
    "https://servicios.ine.es/wstempus/js/es/DATOS_TABLA/37733?tip=AM&", 
    "https://servicios.ine.es/wstempus/js/es/DATOS_TABLA/30841?tip=AM&", 
    "https://servicios.ine.es/wstempus/js/es/DATOS_TABLA/30842?tip=AM&", 
    "https://servicios.ine.es/wstempus/js/es/DATOS_TABLA/30843?tip=AM&", 
    "https://servicios.ine.es/wstempus/js/es/DATOS_TABLA/30844?tip=AM&", 
    "https://servicios.ine.es/wstempus/js/es/DATOS_TABLA/30845?tip=AM&"), 
    rowID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
    14L, 15L, 16L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L), groupID = c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 
    10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider doing this with `possibly/safely`

```
library(purrr)
posdownloadAndStoreJSONData <- possibly(downloadAndStoreJSONData, otherwise = NA_character_)

 out <- pmap(list(df2$json_link, df2$titleFolderLocations, df2$provincia, df2$rowID, df2$groupID, df2$provincesFolderLocationsNames), ~ posdownloadAndStoreJSONData(..1, ..2, ..3, ..4, ..5, ..6))
```

Comment: Thanks! I will certainly keep this. However, when I run the observation on its own, I don't get the error, if I use `possibly` then I will be missing data which I "should" be able to get.

Comment: @user113156 If you are able to return the data by running one observation at a time, then I am guessing that it is due to the sleep not adequate.  Can you change the `Sys.sleep` to a higher number.  May be after the 14th row, it takes a longer time